# Change Pivot Table data source from External Connection to PowerPivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

We have large Excel reports with LOTS of PivotTables. Is there any way to change the data source on the existing PivotTables to change them from an External connection to use the internal Data Model from PowerPivot?

When I choose **PivotTable Analyze > Change Data Source > Change Data Source...**
[image]

it looks like I can change to a different external data source, but not an internal one.
[image]

I looked at VBA solutions, and:

> The [ChangePivotCache method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.changepivotcache) can only be used with a PivotTable that uses data stored on a worksheet as its data source. A run-time error occurs if the ChangePivotCache method is used with a PivotTable that is connected to an external data source.

I would even be happy with a VBA solution that created new pivots and slicers using the old one as a guide. All the columns and tables names are the same. There are just too many pivots to manually migrate!

Comment: What options do you see under "Choose Connection"? Normally the Workbook Data Model is listed under that.

Comment: If the VBA API can't make any changes, the only way to do it might be via `SendKeys`, but that [might not be a stable solution](https://twitter.com/DecimalTurn/status/1096454137431105541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is sadly **NO**. Because that is the restricted manner in which MS designed it. The good part is you can create a `VBA` that loops through all of the `PivotTables` in your `workbook`, reads their properties (such as the fields used in the rows, columns, values, and filters areas), and then creates new `PivotTables` using the `internal Data Model` as the data source and sets their properties to match the original `PivotTables`.

It is not possible to change the data source of an existing `PivotTable` from an `external connection to the internal Data Model from PowerPivot.` When you create a `PivotTable`, you must choose the data source that the `PivotTable (PTbs)`  will use. Once the PivotTable is created, you can change the data source to a different external data source, but you cannot change it to use the internal Data Model.

A [template VBA script](https://paste.c-net.org/WorseHence) that does this It uses internal source for its new PTbs

Comment: I was hoping there was a crafty way to change the source in VBA, but your VBA script looks like it will help the "hard way" of recreating them to be much easier. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Hopefully *MS*  folks  will realize their *smart design* and make changes in future